# I have date format in m/dd/yyyy h:mm and mm/dd/yyyy h:mm and I want output in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in sparksql. But i am getting null

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I have values like 4/5/2017 0:00 and 12/21/2016 0:00
 and I want it in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format . 
I am using this for the task.

```
 stf1.withColumn('approval',unix_timestamp("approval","MM/dd/yyyy h:mm ")
```

where sf1 is the dataframe and approval is the column name that I want to convert to .But I am getting answer as null. and not the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql functions for this.

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df.show()
+-------------+
|            a|
+-------------+
|4/5/2017 0:00|
+-------------+

>>> df.withColumn('b',F.date_format(F.to_date('a','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).show()
+-------------+-------------------+
|            a|                  b|
+-------------+-------------------+
|4/5/2017 0:00|2017-04-05 00:00:00|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I am getting error : Error process:  to_date() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given ). The code is  stf2=stf1.withColumn('approval',F.date_format(F.to_date('approval','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).show()

Comment: I think it is because of spark version. Try this stf2 = stf1.withColumn('approval', F.date_format(F.unix_timestamp('approval', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm').cast("timestamp"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).show()

Comment: It ran without giving any error , but I am getting output like 0017-05-18 12:00:00.0 , Year is not captured correctly .

Comment: what is the input of '0017-05-18 12:00:00.0'?

Comment: 5/18/2017 0:00  . This is the input

Comment: I have just tried and I get the output '2017-05-18 00:00:00'. So I am not sure about the problem

Comment: May be there is some problem in data only , :/

Comment: No, what is the version of spark you have?

Comment: i am using pyspark 1.6

Comment: Can you try this? 
stf1 = stf1.withColumn('approval', date_format(unix_timestamp('approval', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm').cast('timestamp'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))

Comment: @Prazy . same. I am getting output as '0017-05-18 12:00:00.0' only

Comment: This one? 
'from pyspark.sql.functions import *

stf1 = stf1.withColumn('approval', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('approval', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))`

Comment: @Prazy . same output.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the stf1.select('approval').show() output? Also, can you do this? `cols = ['id', 'approval']
vals = [
                (241, '10/09/2018')]

stf1 = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
stf1 = stf1.withColumn('approval', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('approval', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))`

`stf1.show()`

Comment: What is the data type of approval? (how it is defined)?